# ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'Thread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'

Tags: macos, gcloud

The problem occurs with macOs when trying to connect to VM through iap. The same command works from another system with the same credentials, so must be something to do with my local environment.

This is the command I'm trying to run:

```
gcloud compute ssh **** --project=**** --zone=europe-west4-a --tunnel-through-iap
```

And it fails with this error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'Thread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Google gives me no answer whatsoever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a python problem. I guess you are using too new Python3. Please use either Python 3.5 - 3.8 or Python 2.7.9 or higher.

Here is the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#mac

Comment: This solved the problem! Was using Python 3.9

Comment: The documentation inaccurately states that all python 3 versions are supported - it only "recommends" between python 3.5 and 3.8. It should be updated